# How to define new key properties in l3keys

Tags: tcolorbox, expl3, key-value, l3keys, functional

*[Related Meta Question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8969)*

---

From `interface3.pdf`, we can see `l3keys` has provided several key properties such as `.code:n`, `.tl_set:N`, `.usage:n`. But I don't know how to define a new key property.

At this time, my code is like this:

```
\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    keya .code:n = \somemacro {#1},
    keyb .code:n = \othermacro {#1},
  }
```

Now I want to define a new key property `.mycode:n` such that

```
\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    keya .mycode:n = \somemacro {#1},
    keyb .mycode:n = \othermacro {#1},
  }
```

is the same as

```
\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    keya .code:n = \MyFunction \somemacro {#1},
    keyb .code:n = \MyFunction \othermacro {#1},
  }
```

How can I do it? A minimal example is included:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\somemacro[1]{\detokenize{#1}}
\newcommand\othermacro[1]{\detokenize{#1}}
\newcommand\MyFunction[2]{\detokenize{#1,#2}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    keya .code:n = \somemacro {#1},
    keyb .code:n = \othermacro {#1},
  }
\keys_set:nn {test} {keya = a, keyb = b}

\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    keya .code:n = \MyFunction \somemacro {#1},
    keyb .code:n = \MyFunction \othermacro {#1},
  }
\keys_set:nn {test} {keya = a, keyb = b}

\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    keya .mycode:n = \somemacro {#1},
    keyb .mycode:n = \othermacro {#1},
  }
\keys_set:nn {test} {keya = a, keyb = b}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

---

### Question Backgournd

Recently I found `tcolorbox` has an interesting `IfEmptyTF` key, with which you can write

```
IfEmptyTF = {⟨token list⟩}{key=val1}{key=val2}
```

And I decide `tabularray` should have a similar feature, and can make the interface more natural and more powerful to users:

```
key = \tlIfEmptyTF{⟨token list⟩}{\prgReturn{val1}}{\prgReturn{val2}}
```

where `\tlIfEmptyTF` function is from [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package. That is to say, users can use all functions in `functional` package in the values and `tabularray` should replace them with their return values. And this feature should only be enabled if `functional` library is load by users.

To implement this new feature, while keeping the changes to the code minimal, I think it is the best solution to define a new key property in `l3keys`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137385/discussion-on-question-by-l-j-r-how-to-define-new-key-properties-in-l3keys).

Comment: Is it possible for `l3keys` to support per-module (leading parts of a key path) properties?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ No, this is not possible with the current implementation. As demonstrated in my answer below, a key property such as `.code:n` is really just the command with name `\key~prop~>~.code:n`. There is no module prefix anywhere in that name.

Comment: @Gaussler I mean, extending `l3keys` to support ... .

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Would it be possible to rewrite the code of `l3keys` to allow that feature? Absolutely. Is it going to happen? Based on the discussion in this thread, the answer seems to be a resounding no. It seems that the consensus (which I agree with) is that it would not add much to the system. You can already accomplish pretty much anything you want using `.code:n`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ  Maybe the package pgfkeys (manual is in [pgfmanual.pdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)) is of interest. The items for handling properties of keys - i.e. things like ".code" - are called "key-handlers" in pgfmanual.pdf.  In pgfkeys you can implement new key-handlers by defining them as keys in the path `/handlers/`.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't an official way to add new properties. As properties are available for all key creation, and thus form part of the language, adding new ones requires careful consideration. (The team did discuss at length how best to add the '2e-friendly' versions for the new option handler: in the end we did make *e.g.* `.if` an alias for `.legacy_if_set:n` in the same namespace, but this was not a trivial decision.)

As it is, `.code:n` should be used sparingly: most keys are best created to set a variable, which is then queried by the code at run time. If you want to do similar things with several keys, I would expect an internal function to be used

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_key_processor:nn #1#2
  {
    % Payload
  }
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
  {
    keya-a .code:n = \__mypkg_key_processor:nn { a } {#1} ,
    keya-b .code:n = \__mypkg_key_processor:nn { b } {#1} ,
  }
```

The team are [currently considering](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1099) adding a 'post-action' property. This may resolve to allow a 'set a variable then process' approach more readily. (The issue has arisen specifically for issuing debug data, so it may be that a more focussed property is added instead.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137304/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-how-to-define-new-key-properties-in-l3keys).

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly extremely bad style (in other words, *don’t do this*), but I think it’s the only way to accomplish what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\somemacro[1]{\detokenize{#1}}
\newcommand\othermacro[1]{\detokenize{#1}}
\newcommand\MyFunction[2]{\detokenize{#1,#2}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:cpn { key~prop~>~.mycode:n } #1
  { \__keys_cmd_set:nn \l_keys_path_str { \MyFunction #1 } }

\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    keya .code:n = \somemacro {#1},
    keyb .code:n = \othermacro {#1},
  }
\keys_set:nn {test} {keya = a, keyb = b}

\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    keya .code:n = \MyFunction \somemacro {#1},
    keyb .code:n = \MyFunction \othermacro {#1},
  }
\keys_set:nn {test} {keya = a, keyb = b}

\keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    keya .mycode:n = \somemacro {#1},
    keyb .mycode:n = \othermacro {#1},
  }
\keys_set:nn {test} {keya = a, keyb = b}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137383/discussion-on-answer-by-gaussler-how-to-define-new-key-properties-in-l3keys).

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing this in code which I use privately/at home only and where I can take the risk of things needing to be adjusted as soon as the used expl3-internals get changed.I would be reluctant in doing this in code that gets released to to the public/to others who probably cannot handle problems themselves when expl3-internals are changed. Probably, instead of implementing another key-handler, tricky expansion of `\keys_set:nn`'s 2nd argument can be done so that instead of `keya.mycode=...` a macro can be used which expands to `keya.code=\MyFunction...` ? I need to think about it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems adding new key-handlers currently is not supported in l3keys.

If you like code which is more cumbersome to use than what was suggested by Joseph Wright:

How about using a macro `\mymodule_mycode:nw{keya}...,` which expands to `keya.code=\MyFunction...,` and doing some `e`-expansion to `\keys_define:nn`'s second argument?

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_mycode:nw #1 {\__mymodule_mycode:nw {#1}{}} % prevent brace-removal by ensuring a leading {} with delimited #2
\cs_new:Npn \__mymodule_mycode:nw #1#2, {\exp_not:n {#1.code = \MyFunction } \exp_not:n \exp_after:wN {\use_none:n #2,}}

\exp_args:Nne \keys_define:nn {test}
  {
    \mymodule_mycode:nw{keya} = \somemacro {#1},
    \mymodule_mycode:nw{keyb} = \othermacro {#1},
    % wrap things that shall not be affected by e-expansion into \exp_not:n
    % ...
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

If it was not l3keys but pgfkeys you could implement a key-handler `/.mycode` by placing things into the path `/handlers/`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{%
  /handlers/.mycode/.style={\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code={\MyFunction #1}},
  /MyPath/Worldkey/.mycode={World and #1!},
  /MyPath/Moonkey/.mycode={Moon and #1!}
}
\def\MyFunction{Hello, }

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/MyPath/Worldkey={You}}

\pgfkeys{/MyPath/Moonkey={You}}

\end{document}
```

[image]